# jQuery Tokeninput+colorbox fails on ipad/iphone

Tags: jquery-plugins, colorbox, tokenize

I'm using http://colorpowered.com/colorbox/ and jquery Tokeninput without problems - untill I combine them and want to tokenize an input field in an colorbox.

I load my file in a iframe through colorbox and jquery Tokeninput loads up suggestions just fine untill I want to touch one of the items in the populated list.

All is good on my regular computer. The problem only exist when using iPad/iPhone (hav'nt tried other touch devices).

Any ideas as to where the problem belongs? I'm not sure whether it's colorbox or jquery Tokeninput to blame?

Just to check I loaded http://loopj.com/jquery-tokeninput/demo.html in a colorbox - same problem. The demo page works just fine on iPad when not in an colorbox.

/anders
denmark

Answer (score 0):

I've been having similar problems with other contents in colourbox. I think the problem is that iPhone Safari doesn't support position:fixed;